# Moving MS Exchange 2007 to another machine

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, exchange-migration

We have a machine that has been chugging along with the burden of both Exchange and DC and DNS all with SBS 2008.

We have a better machine now and I'd like to move Exchange 2007 to that machine and take it off of this machine. In fact, I'm planning on formatting the old machine and get rid of SBS all together because it is making the machine SLOW.

How would I go about making the move?

I've read on previous versions of Exchange (2000), that all you do is install Exchange on the new machine and then start moving mailboxes one after the other.

Well, what about all the different rules we have in place? How do those get moved? How do we de-commission the old exchange and set up the new exchange as the primary one?
Come to think of it, how do we have both exchanges recognize each other on the same domain?

TIA

Comment: Nothing? Wow, I was hoping for any clue..

Answer (score 2):

You need to go with standard path that you would normally do with adding additional AD/DNS, and additional Exchange 2007/2010 server.

The following steps should be able to help you out but I suggest you read more migration guides (or question) for each product you're going to migrate.

1. Install Windows 2008 (R2) server and add it as a member server of your existing domain.
2. Run ADPREP /FORESTPREP from the 2008 DVD on the SBS server to update the schema
3. Add new Active Directory role on new Windows 2008 (R2) server and then run DCPROMO on your new server.
4. During DCPROMO you will be asked about making new domain or making it a domain controller of the existing domain. When asked about being DNS server do it as well.
5. (optional, only if you use DHCP server on SBS) Install the DHCP role on your new server and create the scopes identical to the ones on your SBS server with the exception of the DNS server needs to be specified as your new server.  Authorize the server and activate the scope.  This will cause the SBS service to be disabled and the clients will get a new IP address from your new DHCP server.
6. Update your SBS server so it is now pointing to your new Domain Controller for DNS and restart the NETLOGON service.
7. Install your second server and configure it to use the new DNS server for DNS and join it to the domain as a member server.
8. Install Exchange 2010 as an additional server of your existing Exchange Organization (to do this the Exchange on your SBS server must be running Service Pack 2)
9. Follow the Microsoft Guide for transitioning to Exchange 2007/2010: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124008.aspx
10. Once you have installed Exchange 2007/2010 and moved the mailboxes leave both Exchange servers running for a few days this way Outlook will automatically update itself with the new server name so you won't have to do it manually.
11. Once all the mailboxes/public folders/OAB's etc have been moved then uninstall Exchange 2007 from the SBS server. Give it some time before doing so.
12. Recreate the shares that are in your SBS server on your new server.
13. Backup and restore the data to it's new location
14. Update drive mapping/ active directory attributes (home folder/profile path)
15. Transfer the FSMO roles to your new Domain Controller as per: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324801 (this is for Windows 2003 but should be similar for Windows 2008)
16. Run DCPROMO on the SBS server to remove active directory from it
17. Shutdown SBS server. Remove it from the domain. Optionally you could wait a few days/weeks before finally removing SBS from domain to be sure you have not missed anything.

You will also need to update any rules on firewall's you have forwarding port 25, 587 (pop3/imap if you're using it too) and 443 to your SBS server to the new Exchange Server.

This should do it, but make sure you read some additional information on how to do stuff, maybe make a copy of your SBS and play with it in VM machines or so before you do final cut.

Answer (score 1):

Well, lots of questions there. Having done several Exchange migrations and new installs as well as working with Small Business Server all I can say is that if you are asking such basic questions then I would suggest you guys hire a consultant to help with the migration.

To start with, Microsoft will not let you move Exchange off of the main server. So unless you buy a copy of Exchange and all of the CALs you are at a dead end already.

Your best bet may to buy some imaging software that will let you do hardware restors to different hardware.

HTH

Mike

Comment: The reason I'm asking about moving exchange is because we have a pretty complex rule set in place.

Another is because we are moving away from SBS and onto a W2K8r2/Exchange 2007 combo.

CALs and Licences have been acquired from the local MS Partner. 

I wasn't looking at moving the image from one machine to another, rather something along the lines of a two node SCC, but I'm not an expert in the field.

Still though, I'll take it up with the powers that be here and see if we can hire an external consultant.

Cheers.